# Laravel config:clear broke the application

Tags: php, laravel

I intended to write `cache:clear` and endup writing `config:clear` and broke the website.

I get error 500 now, with the log:

```
local.ERROR: Class 'Stripe\Laravel\StripeServiceProvider' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Stripe\\Laravel\\StripeServiceProvider' not found at /home/so/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:208)

local.ERROR: Class view does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class view does not exist at /home/so/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:788)

Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /home/so/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:788
```

I tried to do `composer dump:autoload` but it returns the error:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Stripe\Laravel\StripeServiceProvider' not found
```

Help, how do I solve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** (temporarily).

The class was being called in `config/app.php` under `providers`, commenting solved the issue.